# cordova cant access external scripts, files, images

Tags: file, cordova, load, external

This is driving me nuts.

I have two versions of my app, a barebones version and an advanced version.  I messed up some modules/plugins in the advanced version so I rebuilt it from scratch in a new directory.  Copied all the necessary www/js/img folders to the newly created one.

I verified i have installed all the same plugins, modules and packages - I then am able to build the app successfully and run it successfully.  However, any reference to external scripts or files are getting a "404 (Not Found)" error on the console logs.  The barebones app can still pull in the google maps script and I have compared the two config.xml files and can't see anything that would cause an issue.

One is in the index.html:

And the other are jpg images loaded from the IONIC website - part of their standard tabs template.

The errors I am getting:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&

and

GET https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/514549811765211136/9SgAuHeY.png 404 (Not Found) ionic.bundle.js:11568
...and 5 more img png/jpg errors similar to this one.

For the life of me I cant' figure out why the newly rebuilt app isn't allowed to pull in external files or scripts.  Any and all help is appreciated.

In my config.xml file I have the following defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.testapp765534" 
  version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
  xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <name>TestApp</name>
  <description> 
    A test mapping app. 
  </description>
  <author href="http://testapp.org/" email="info@testapp.org"> 
    testapp DEV TEAM
  </author>
  <access origin="*" />
  <access origin="http://*.google.com" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
  </platform>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param onload="true" name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
  </feature>
</widget>
```

For the record I also have the following plugins installed:

```
android.support.v4 21.0.1 "Android Support v4"
com.google.playservices 23.0.0 "Google Play Services for Android"
com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.4 "Keyboard"
cordova-plugin-device 1.0.0 "Device"
net.orworks.cordovaplugins.cordovasqlite 1.5.0 "CordovaSQLite"
org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.13 "Console"
org.apache.cordova.device-motion 0.2.11 "Device Motion"
org.apache.cordova.device-orientation 0.3.11 "Device Orientation"
org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.3.0 "Notification"
org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.12 "Geolocation"
org.apache.cordova.globalization 0.3.4 "Globalization"
org.apache.cordova.splashscreen 1.0.0 "Splashscreen"
org.apache.cordova.statusbar 0.1.10 "StatusBar"
org.apache.cordova.vibration 0.3.13 "Vibration"
```

Comment: did you update the cordova version on the new app you created?

Comment: I am running Cordova 5.0 for all my projects.

Answer (score 2):

Install https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist this plugin then it works.